# ¿Cómo centrar un fa-icon?

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap

Quisiera saber: **¿Cómo centrar los items dentro de un `<div>`?**, en particular si el item es un *fa-icon*. ¿Cuál es el error?. He probado: Alinear texto del objeto, alinear items, margin:0 auto, definir un estilo. Nada me ha resultado. Agradezco su colaboración y comparto el fragmento del código donde se visualiza el error.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="section-overview">
      <h3 style="color:#062156">Enlaces Relacionados:</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-9">
    <ul class="thumbnails">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
        <div class="relacionados-item">
          <h4><a target="_blank" href="http://*">Texto.</a></h4>
          <h5>Texto 2.</h5>
          <a href="/videos.html" target="_blank">
            <i class="fa fa-cogs fa-4x"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

¿Quisiera saber **cómo alinear el icono fa-cogs** para que se visualice centrado en relación a su texto superior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema es que no estás aplicando bien el sistema de rejilla de Boostrap. Tienes un `col-lg-3` seguido de un `col-lg-9` que suman una fila seguido por un `col-*` **dentro** pero que no tiene su correspondiente `row`.

Para centrarlo sólo tienes que usar la clase `text-center` de Bootstrap.

```css
.thumbnails {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="section-overview">
      <h3 style="color:#062156">Enlaces Relacionados:</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-9">
    <ul class="thumbnails">
      <li>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="relacionados-item text-center">
              <h4><a target="blanck" href="http://*">Texto.</a></h4>
              <h5>Texto 2.</h5>
              <a href="/videos.html" target="_blank">
                <i class="fa fa-cogs fa-4x"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

¿El error?: *Incluir dentro de la misma división al texto y al fa-icon.*
**Solución:** Sacar el contenido que no me interesa centrar del `<div>`, y usar css sólo para ubicar el icono en la posición `center` deseada. 
¿Cómo sería el nuevo código?
**HTML:**

```
   <h4><a target="blanck" href="http://*">Texto.</a></h4>
   <h5>Texto 2.</h5>    
   <div id="info">
       <a href="/"><i class="fa fa-cogs fa-4x"></i></a>
   </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#info {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

Comment: Cambia `target=blanck` por `target=blank` para no llevar a otros a errores. Échale un ojo al css en este otro ejemplo por si complementa algo tu respuesta: http://www.bootply.com/132008

Comment: De hecho es `target="_blank"`